# Must every group with a one-half morphism embed into a ring in which the morphism is division by 2?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $\alpha$ be an endomorphism of a group $G$. We say $\alpha$ is a *one-half morphism* if $\alpha(gg) = g$ for all $g \in G$. The existence of such a morphism in fact implies that $G$ is abelian, hence the name "one-half morphism" rather than "square-root morphism".

A few examples:

- Any cyclic group of odd order has a one-half morphism.
- More generally, if $G$ is finite, $G$ has a one-half morphism if and only if it is abelian and has no element of order 2, if and only if $G$ is a direct product of cyclic groups of odd order.
- If $G$ is the additive group of a ring in which 2 is invertible, then multiplication by $1/2$ in the ring gives a one-half morphism of $G$.
- And certainly any direct sum/product of groups with one-half morphisms yields a group with a one-half morphism.

There are groups $G$ with one-half morphisms which are not simply division by 2 in a ring structure on $G$, e.g., the direct sum of all odd prime cyclic groups. But this embeds into the direct product, in which the one-half morphism is again just division by 2.

My question is: is this always true? I.e, is every $G$ with a one-half morphism $\alpha$ simply a subgroup of the additive group of a ring in which $\alpha$ is division by 2?

Comment: A question whether every abelian group is an additivie subgroup of some unital ring is interesting on its own. Note that not every abelian group can be turned into a unital ring. In fact there are abelian groups such that the only valid multiplication on them is the zero multiplication, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_{p^\infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $G$ has the structure of a module over $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$, where we fiat that multiplication by $1/2$ is given by $\alpha$. Then $G$ embeds into the tensor algebra (or the symmetric algebra, if you want a commutative ring) of $G$ over $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$, and on $G$, $\alpha$ is division by $2$.